# Android Migrate from SQLite to Room

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I have application which uses Sqlite database and i have three tables in my database. Now i want to Switch to Room Library , i can successfully create tables in room but i can't figure out a way to Define relationships between objects. I visited [android developers](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships)
site but i don't know how this applies to me .
Here are the Queries i am using to create database in sqlite

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
id            INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
category_name         NOT NULL
                      UNIQUE,
category_id           NOT NULL
                      UNIQUE
);


CREATE TABLE quotes_table (
    id          INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    quote               UNIQUE,
    category_id         NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE favourites (
    id            INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    quote,
    category_name,
    date          DATETIME DEFAULT (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
);
```

This is how i query data from my database

```
    public Cursor getAllCategories() {

    String query = "SELECT * FROM categories ;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        openDatabase();
        cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return cursor;
}

public Cursor getQuotes(String catId) {

    String query = "SELECT * FROM quotes_table INNER JOIN categories  ON quotes_table.category_id = categories.category_id
     WHEREquotes_table.category_id like " + catId;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        openDatabase();
        cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return cursor;
}
```

Can anyone please help . I searched a lot but couldn't find anything that could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you have created entity classes for your tables.

You can create an additional class for representing the relationship between these two tables.

```
public class QuotesWithCategories{
    @Embedded public Quote quote ;
    @Relation(
         parentColumn = "category_id",
         entityColumn = "category_id"
    )
    public Category category;
}
```

Now to fetch the record, you can define the below function in your DAO.

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM quotes_table WHERE quotes_table.category_id LIKE :catId")
public List<QuotesWithCategories> getQuotesWithCategories(int catId");
```